# How do I add edit/delete buttons to a custom module items list?

Tags: forms, database

I have a custom form on my development site for visitors to create requests, with 3 fields: name, contact, and request.

This is the code in RequestForm.php.

```
public function getFormId() {
  return 'request_form';
}
```

This is the form builder.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['name'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('имя'),
  ];
  $form['contact'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('контакт'),
  ];
  $form['reqtext'] = [
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => $this->t('Текст заявки'),
  ];
  $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
  $form['actions']['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Отправить заявку'),
    '#button_type' => 'primary',
  ];
  return $form;
}
```

The validation handler isn't implemented; I just need to come up with the basics. The user data is stored in the database.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface 
$form_state) {
  $name = $form_state->getValue('name');
  $contact = $form_state->getValue('contact');
  $reqtext = $form_state->getValue('reqtext');

  $connection = \Drupal::database();
  $result = $connection->insert('request')
    ->fields([
      'name' =>  $name,
      'contact' => $contact,
      'reqtext' =>  $reqtext ,
    ])
    ->execute();
}
```

The requests are saved in the database, and I need to view, edit, and delete them. 
I created a route to list all of them, using the following code.

#### .routing.yml

```
request.list:
path: '/admin/request-list'
defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\request\Controller\RequestController::showdata'
    _title: 'Отобразить все заявки'
requirements:
    _role: 'administrator'
```

#### The route controller

```
class RequestController extends ControllerBase {
public function showdata() {
  $listall = \Drupal::database()->select('request', 'n');
  $listall->fields('n', array('requestid', 'name', 'contact', 
'reqtext'));
  $result=$listall->execute()->fetchAll();

  // Create the row element.
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($result as $row => $content) {
    $rows[] = array(
      'data' => array($content->requestid, $content->name, $content-        
>contact, $content->reqtext));
  }

  // Create the header.
  $header = array('requestid', 'name', 'contact', 'reqtext');

  $output = array(
    '#type' => 'table',
    #theme.
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows
  );
  return $output;
}
```

How and where  do I implement buttons to edit/delete a certain request?

I'm seeing something like a table:

```
Num Name    Contact        Request                     Options
1   Alex    +7898231231    I need a 10 litres of oil   Edit/Delete
2   John    +7231231231    I need a 50 litres of oil   Edit/Delete
```

I must be missing something, I guess. There is the "right" way to do this in Drupal 8. 
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question is too broad for us. You could add links to the page showing the table, you could add a submission button to the edit form to delete the entry. In either the cases, we would end up writing code for a feature you didn't implement. Our task is not writing code on demand, but saying what is wrong in the code the OP is using.

Comment: You can find an example of what Drupal core does in /admin/content, which the page listing all the nodes created for a site.

Comment: **¡¡¡Always only pass English strings to the** `t()` **function!!!**

Comment: The [Examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples/releases/8.x-1.x-dev) comes with a sub module called [Content Entity Example](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/content_entity_example) which goes over this. Basically copy the module and modify to your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;

[...]

// Create the row element.
$rows = array();
foreach ($result as $row => $content) {
  $rows[] = array('data' => array($content->requestid);
  $rows[] = array('data' => array($content->name);
  $rows[] = array('data' => array($content->contact);
  $rows[] = array('data' => array($content->reqtext);
  //Actions.
  $edit_link = Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Edit'), 'myrouter.edit_form'['id'=>$content->requestid], [
        'absolute' =>
          TRUE
      ]);

$delete_link = Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Delete'),'myrouter.delete_form',['id'=>$content->requestid], ['absolute' => TRUE]);


$build_link_action = [
      'action_edit' => [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#value' => $edit_link->toString(),
      '#tag' => 'div',
      '#attributes'=>['class'=>['action-edit']]
     ],
     'action_delete' => [
       '#type' => 'html_tag',
       '#value' => $delete_link->toString(),
       '#tag' => 'div',
       '#attributes'=>['class'=>['action-edit']]
       ]
      ];


 $rows[] = ['data' => \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($build_link_action)];
}

// Create the header.
$headers = array('requestid', 'name', 'contact', 'reqtext','options');


$output['results_table'] = [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#header' => $headers,
  '#empty' => $this->t('There are no items to display.')
];
return $output
```

Comment: Hey vinhdv, your answer is really helpful as always, but you should definitely internalize [Drupal coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards). If you have some nice IDE you even can make it apply them automatically.

Comment: Please don't answer questions with just a code dump - while it might technically solve the problem, it's not a useful answer for the OP and future visitors. A useful answer will explain what the OP has done wrong in their current approach, and how the code you're supplying solves or works around this. Many thanks